# Javascript, what are (n) and the square brackets doing in this function?

Tags: javascript

Just got a couple of questions to help me understand this script, as where it is OP, the explanation is pretty thin.

1) `(n)` is passed into the functions plusDivs and showDivs. How does this `(n)` work? Is it just an empty container to store the data in the function.

2) With this line `x[i].style.display="none";` and `x[slideIndex-1].style.display="block";` with the square brackets used, is the code inside the square brackets executed first? What are the square brackets doing or called in this instance.

Although functions are explained in online tutorials in a basic way, some of this information I'm asking is quite hard to find out so would appreciate some help .

Thanks Emma.

JS:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 } 
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length };
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<button style="border:none; font-size: 22px;background-color:black; color:white; position:fixed; top:30%; left:5%" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
<button id="rightbutton" style="border:none; font-size: 22px;background-color:black; color:white;position:fixed; top:30%; right:5%" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
```

Comment: hi, we dont know because we cant see where this function `plusDivs();` called and what argument you passed into.

Comment: square brackets are used for selecting nth element in an array

Comment: hi Colin, I've edited the original question to add the left and right arrows that call the plusDivs function. It's a slideshow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are portions of code that take caller-supplied information called "arguments" and use them in the code. The syntax of a function is

```
function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

If the above function were to be called:

```
(function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
})(1, 1)
```

The result would be `2`.

The `[`brackets`]` are subscript operators. In the context of arrays, they take a numeric index and return the element at that location:

```
[1, 2, 3][0] === 1
```

In the context of objects, they take a key and return the mapped value:

```
(({
     'foo' : 'bar'
})['foo']) === 'bar'
```

In your case, the function `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, so the brackets denote array subscription and are used to retrieve an element of the array.

Comment: Yes thanks, In my code example, am I correct in saying that code in the 2 lines of code with [i] and [slideindex-1] are evaluated first because the code in [] has operator precedence and then the computed values from inside the [] are passed to compute the rest of the line of code. I know code in () works like this but not sure about code in [] - thanks Emma.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The expression inside the brackets must be evaluated in order to get the index and evaluate the rest of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) (n) is passed into the functions plusDivs and showDivs. How does this (n) work? Is it just an empty container to store the data in the function.

an integer passed into plusDivs() function, its mean by pressing buttons you pass "-1 and +1" integer as argument to your function and in your function it will add/contact it from you current slide index that will cause your slider moves to forward(next slide) or backward(prev slide)

> 2) With this line x[i].style.display="none"; and x[slideIndex-1].style.display="block"; with the square brackets used, is the code inside the square brackets executed first? What are the square brackets doing or called in this instance.

As i mentioned in comments they are for finding nth element inside an array. at first of your code you find all slides and cached them into a variable, so when you need to find nth slide youmost use something like this `slide[slide number 2]` (this is just pseudo code)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the answers in this case are very clear. 
The `(n)` and `i` in your question are just free variables. They could be any letter (e.g `i` could be `'b'` or some other letter).

They are just naming and referencing the var properties.